# Primefaces override CSS correctly

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, overriding

I have started to use primefaces. I want to override css of p:button I can change the color but it is not correct. There is something like gradient and white spaces between text and background. Also don't know how to change hover style(blue glow shadow). How can I correctly change css? Can I find somewhere default css and change it like I want?

IMG 
http://static.pokazywarka.pl/i/3078120/213294/pf.jpg

Comment: No it is not a duplicate. I would like to know what are the elements of css of given pf component. And as You see I have explained my problem. I know HOW to change css but it doesn't work fine.

Comment: Have a look in your browser using firebug or similars, you'll be able to inspect the elements and their css. Then change them as it is explained in the referenced question

Comment: Good hint but I still cant remove wite line on top of the button when I change the color.

Comment: Your question would be better explained with the current code rather than an image

Comment: Like I have written above, I have only changed the color of button with background-color property. Result is on the img.

Comment: There are probably a padding and/or a margin.. you need to set them to 0px. As adviced use a debugger/developer tool to see the css style code that is generated and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: I can't slove it. What is interesting by default this line is visible too but in case of default color not so much - (try hover it) http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/button.xhtml